# Multiple User types and Identity

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

In my project, I am currently working on user roles (claims) and registration.

I am struggling with which approach I should use or if there is any source I can base on.
I have two types of application users (related to the app's domain), let's say they are Lecturer and Student, these entities differ by a few fields so I wanted to have them separated.

How should I design the entities now?

There are a few cases but I'm not sure how to cover them.

User can be Lecturer

User can be Student

User can be both Lecturer and Student (at the same time)

How do I manage that?

I was thinking about adding a foreign key to each entity (Lecturer/Student/AnyOtherType) to reference IdentityUser and during the registration define the type of user by claims

```
userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Lecturer"))
userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Student"));
```

Do you think it is a good idea?
How to handle incoming requests based on user role? I know I can use something similar to the following example in some Services, but ideally, I would like to avoid unnecessary calls to the DB just to filter out the needed data in the Service

```
user.IsInRole("lecturer")
```

I'm focusing on DDD rn.

Comment: I think you should have a user table to store all shared information, and put role and user id etc. into an separated table.

Answer (score 1):

You can create another role **Lecturer-Student-Role** and add the user to three roles: **Student-Role**, **Lecturer-Role** and **Lecturer-Student-Role**.

If you have operations in your system where only a user with the role Lecturer-Student-Role can perform, you can check by using the following code:

```
bool isLecturerStudentRole = await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Lecturer-Student-Role");
```

Additionally, to address the handling incoming requests based on the User role, if you have either a controller or API operations and you want to check authorization for specific endpoints, you can use the attribute Authorize with a specific role as well. Check the example below:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Lecturer-Student-Role")]
public class MyController : BaseController
{

}
```

You can have separated tables with a foreign key referenced to the User.Id table. So in this way you can manage different columns for specific users in the system.

PS: It is a good practice to use a prefix/suffix Role when creating it.